# Best programming language to implement DBSCAN algorithm querying a MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I've to implement the DBSCAN algorithm.
Assuming to start from this pseudocode

```
DBSCAN(D, eps, MinPts)
   C = 0
   for each unvisited point P in dataset D
      mark P as visited
      NeighborPts = regionQuery(P, eps)
      if sizeof(NeighborPts) < MinPts
         mark P as NOISE
      else
         C = next cluster
         expandCluster(P, NeighborPts, C, eps, MinPts)

expandCluster(P, NeighborPts, C, eps, MinPts)
   add P to cluster C
   for each point P' in NeighborPts 
      if P' is not visited
         mark P' as visited
         NeighborPts' = regionQuery(P', eps)
         if sizeof(NeighborPts') >= MinPts
            NeighborPts = NeighborPts joined with NeighborPts'
      if P' is not yet member of any cluster
         add P' to cluster C

regionQuery(P, eps)
   return all points within P's eps-neighborhood
```

My code has to run on an **Amazon EC2** Instance with Ubuntu Linux 64 bit.

The function **regionQuery** queries a **MongoDB** database to obtain all points within P's eps-neighborhood.

So, according to you, what is the best programming language to implement it to improve performances? **C**, **PHP**, **Java** (I don't think)?

Comment: just curious; how is `C = next cluster` implemented? is there a unmentioned cluster list somewhere?

Comment: Note that DBSCAN is properly spelled DBSCAN, it is an abbreviation. N for example is for Noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume  that you have a lot of points and need results fast  - otherwise you can use almost anything.

It seems  like map-reduce job for me

Map part would be loop "for each unvisited point"    and should emit data construct containing 
neighbors, candidate clusters  and whatever else.  In case point is classified as noise it should emit nothing.

Cluster expansion shall go into reduce and possibly finalize part -  also language choice would be javascript and everything would  happen inside mongo

Comment: In the beginning, all points are "unvisited". Sorry, this won't work with a single map-reduce step. Plus, how is the mapper to construct neighbors?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse After Konstantin's advice, I've realized a version of DBScan-MapReduce full working in MongoDB.
When it will be ready, I'll post here ;)

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda Sorry for delay, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12749227/915502) it is :)

Answer (score 3):

Google for "parallel DBSCAN", and you will find a number of articles discussing how to parallelize this algorithm. Usually, it will change the algorithm quite a bit, for example it will require merging clusters.

Canopy pre-clustering may be a good preprocessing step for DBSCAN, too.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to reply to my own question. I finally implemented a MapReduce version of DBSCAN algorithm.
You can find it [**here**](https://github.com/MarcoSero/Event-Detection) (Hadoop).

This is the pseudo-code of how it works:

```
function map(P, eps, MinPts)
    if P is unvisited then
        mark P as visited
        NeighborPts = regionQuery(P, eps)
        if sizeof(NeighborPts) < MinPts then
            do nothing
        else
            mark P as clusterized
            prepare the key
            create new cluster C
            C.neighborPoints = NeighborPts
            C.points = P
            emit(key, C)

function reduce(key, clusters, eps, MinPts)
    finalC is the final cluster
    for all C in clusters do
        finalC.points = finalC.points ∪ C.points
        for all P in C.neighborPoints do
            if P′ is not visited then
                mark P′ as visited
                NeighborPts′ = regionQuery(P′,eps)
                if sizeof(NeighborPts′) ≥ MinPts then
                    NeighborPts = NeighborPts ∪ NeighborPts′
                end if
            end if
            if P′ is not yet member of any cluster then
                add P′ to cluster C
            end if
```

Comment: How do you do efficient `regionQuery` on MapReduce?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thanks geospatial indexing in MongoDB, I simply run a query

Comment: Which likely kills your performance. Sorry, but this looks like the most naive and least performant way of computing DBSCAN in MapReduce. And I'd not at all be surprised if - in particular for 2D data - any classic database with a single-host DBSCAN will kick your ass performance wise, sorry. Did you benchmark yet?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse there are _a lot_ of reason why we chosen MongoDB and we implemented the system in this way.  
Please, enlighten me, how would you have done?

Comment: The point is: **it is *not* MapReduce anymore** when you flood your database server(s) with region queries. That does not at all scale in a MapReduce way, and the functions are neither maps, nor reduces with the MapReduce scheme. So while you are (ab-)using your MR engine, it isn't a formal MapReduce anymore (and you lose all the performance guarantees). Have a look at your CPU usages. The mapper and reducer probably are idle 99%, while the DB server is under max load. You need to use a parallel way of doing the range joins; and that *cannot* be a MapReduce program, because it is not linear.

Comment: So, **did you benchmark**? Try running this in your setup, and try putting the data into a true clustering thing like ELKI and run it there. Just choose a data set that the latter can handle on a single core. I'd be interested in seeing the numbers of what ELKI (which has an excellent DBSCAN implementation and R*-trees) does on a single core and what your hack does on k cores.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks for the explanation. The algorithm runs with Hadoop in a 16-core machine. MongoDB is in the same machine.
Hadoop splits the input to create 16 map tasks and 16 reduce tasks. Here you can see a bench of CPU usage with a small input: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2femo0635x1orpv/newrelic.png

Comment: On a *single* host you do not need MapReduce at all. MapReduce is *only* sensible for distributed operation, because it allows the system to optimize data *distribution*. Seriously, do more **benchmarking**.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Hadoop MapReduce was for us the simplest solution to implement this algorithm taking advantage of concurrency and, in the future, to easily scale datas. We are satisfied of our benchmarks.

Comment: with your code Hadoop does not help you to scale, it's merely a tool that spams mongodb with queries in parallel -- mongodb scalability determines your code scalability

Comment: @Marco Sero I wanted to know that in the map, what is the structure of the key that is to be emitted. I feel your solution is a very good solutions as it is really hard to parallelize DBSCAN.