# Need assistance with implementing DBSCAN on Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement DBSCAN on MR and am using the intuition from the link I have pasted below

```
http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.com/2012/05/distributed-dbscan-intuition.html
```

[Best programming language to implement DBSCAN algorithm querying a MongoDB database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775133/best-programming-language-to-implement-dbscan-algorithm-querying-a-mongodb-datab)

My question was how do I compute the initial distance matrix. I dont want to run a hadoop job just for calculating the distance matrix and store it in memory as I wont be a good design. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reading my blog.

Yes the distance matrix to compute is very difficult.

I have applied a minhash clustering (mahout has an implementation as well) to find vectors that are quite similar. So you don't have to compute the whole distance matrix, but that of vectors that are similar.

So my advice for you would be to use mahout's minhashing to find clusters of similar vectors. Then compute a smaller distance matrix for them and then apply the rest of the bullet points I written in my post:

- Extract adjacent points from your "mini" cluster
- Run a connected component algorithm from the resulting graph (There are implementations of it with MapReduce, Giraph and Hama)

So that is basically it. Can't open source this whole stages unfortunately, so that's what the whole procedure takes.

Comment: Great your solution makes sense. Thank you. So the next step after that would be use the setup function of the map and initialize the mini clusters and use a custom partitioner to send the record to the correct map task.

Comment: Hey Thomas, I also had another suggestion, instead of using min hash, a more easier approach would be use the run function(defined here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943472/how-the-recordreader-in-hadoop-works-how-it-calls-the-methods-how-the-values). Create the distance matrix in the setup as we will have all the records that have been assigned to a map task. What are your views about it?

Comment: @anonymous123 I don't think this is feasible, because this will only give you nearest neighbours in your input chunk not globally.

Comment: Hmm, yup, I will the closest neighbours in a particular chunk and not globally, you are correct.